# How to use multiple forms inside <rich:tabPanel> with switchType="server"?

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

We switched from RichFaces 3 to 4 and have some conceptual problems with `<rich:tabPanel>`... with RichFaces 3 you could do something like that:

```
<rich:tabPanel switchType="server">
    <rich:tab header="A">
        <h:form>
            <h:commandButton value="A1" />
        </h:form>
        <h:form>
            <h:commandButton value="A2" />
        </h:form>
    </rich:tab>
    <rich:tab header="B">
        <h:form>
            <h:commandButton value="B" />
        </h:form>
    </rich:tab>
    <rich:tab header="C">
        <h:form>
            <h:commandButton value="C" />
        </h:form>
    </rich:tab>
</rich:tabPanel>
```

That no longer works with JSF 2 and RichFaces 4 – for `<rich:tabPanel>` needs its own `<h:form>` for `switchType="server"` or `"ajax"`... only client works without a form. So we now would have to build it like that:

```
<h:form>
    <rich:tabPanel switchType="server">
        <rich:tab header="A">
            <h:commandButton value="A1" />
            <h:commandButton value="A2" />
        </rich:tab>
        <rich:tab header="B">
            <h:commandButton value="B" />
        </rich:tab>
        <rich:tab header="C">
            <h:commandButton value="C" />
        </rich:tab>
    </rich:tabPanel>
</form>
```

That works... but I'm no longer able to separate between `A1` and `A2` which have been separate forms before.

How can we solve that problem without using `switchType="client"`?

Comment: What are you trying to separate?

Comment: Some of our more complex UI use different forms to submit discreet datasets which must be handled separately. We could try to re-model and work around that but this would take much time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The multi forms support in rich:tabPanel ticket has been just recently rejected with recommendation to use `a4j:region`:

> This will not be implemented, <a4j:region> can be used to limit the
>   scope of execution inside a tab.

https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-11306

Comment: you've got the score for the related ticket / link... thanks.

Comment: That worked... but `<rich:tabPanel switchType="ajax">` had problems when using `<a4j:commandButton execute="@region" render="@all">` – we had to use `<a4j:commandButton execute="@region" render="@form,messages">`. Otherwise switching tabs rendered content in wrong tabs sometimes appending 2 tabs in 1.

Answer (score 1):

You can can limit the scope of the `<a4j:commandButton execute="@region">` with @execute. Probably the easiest approach would be to wrap the data in an `<a4j:region>` and set `execute="@region"` on the button.

Comment: ...might be solution.

Comment: `<h:commandButton>` doesn't have @execute, `<a4j:commandButton>` does.